# rich text to plain text

Tags: list, rich-text

List consists from Title (Single line of text) and Content (Multiple lines of text - Enhanced rich text) columns.

I need to get snippet from Content column(~125 first symbols). 
I've found that text in Content column formatted and contains html tags.
I want to know, how I can programmatically **get plain text** from rich text? I know that I can use Regex, but it's not nice solution.

Have an answer?

Answer (score 5):

Didn't test, but you can probably use [SPFieldMultiLineText.GetFieldValueAsText Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldmultilinetext.getfieldvalueastext.aspx) :

```
SPListItem yourItem = ....; // obtain the SPListItem with any method
SPFieldMultiLineText field = (SPFieldMultiLineText)yourItem.Fields["Content"]; 

string text = field.GetFieldValueAsText (yourItem["Content"]);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you dont want to use this

```
string content = Regex.Replace(textWithHTML, "<.*?>", string.Empty);
```

you can use this, this returns the `SPListItem` as normal text

```
private string getFieldAsText(SPListItem item, string fieldName, string captionName)
{
            return ReferenceEquals(item[fieldName], null) ? string.Empty :
                item.Fields[captionName].GetFieldValueAsText(item[fieldName]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you need:

```
const string htmlRegex = "<.*?>";

static string StripHTML (string inputString)
{
   // Removes all the HTML tags and returns the string with the 125 first characters
   return Regex.Replace(inputString, htmlRegex, string.Empty).Remove(125);
}
```

Comment: is there a solution without further processing? I mean is there method extracting plain text from SPListItem?

Comment: @Nurlan Not that I am aware of, no.

Comment: @Nurlan Yes, see the answers. While this might work, I prefer the other methods.