# Sharepoint List Column to pdf

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have a sharepoint list column which contains rich text and I used Itextsharp to convert the content of the column to a pdf.

The problem is that html tags are showing up in the pdf when I open it. How to remove them. I am pasting the code I used below, Please suggest necessary changes.

```
               foreach(SPListItem oitem in oListCollection)
                    {
                        string _strPDF = Convert.ToString(oitem["Description"]);
                        string _strPDFTitle = Convert.ToString(oitem["Title"]);
                        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Administrator\" +  _strPDFTitle + ".pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);

                        Document doc = new Document();
                        PdfWriter oPdfwriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);
                        doc.Open();
                        doc.Add(new Paragraph(_strPDF));
                        doc.Close();
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely convinced this is a 100% SharePoint question, but a more general **How to remove HTML tags in iTextSharp?**, the query *"itextsharp remove html*" seems to be a popular on Google.

But that aside I would suggest you use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack) to parse the markup, and then call `htmldoc.DocumentNode.InnerText` as used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3140991).

Also I hope you have noticed the license on iTextSharp, I can't comment on it myself, but I know there are a lot of discussions about it. There exists [alternatives](http://www.nuget.org/packages/PdfSharp/) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Description field a plain text field, or one of the formatted types?

See [HTML from Rich Text Field as Plain Text](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/35332/html-from-rich-text-field-as-plain-text) to strip formatting and get the value as plain text.

Also, you do not need to call Convert.ToString() on Title and Description since both are already string

Comment: The link you gave is for `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client`, and not SSOM as OP has. But I believe one can do something like `list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("Description").GetFieldValueAsText(oItem)`

Comment: Uh. Right. It's late :P But it comes down to just formatting strings as you suggested, not really specific to SharePoint

Comment: Well, perhaps, but the `GetFieldValueAsText` is a SharePoint-specific method. If you change your answer to use that I will upvote you and so you would have the correct answer. I will not delete mine as HtmlAgilityPack can make it easier to do more complicated alterations beside just html->plain string.